# What web framework for iOS?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, xcode

I've been wondering if there was a proprietary kit from Apple for creating a server  that you can test and develop https functions (i.e sql and php data) starting  in x code (ad hoc included) for iOS development.

I've read a bit off https://www.apple.com/develepor though I am looking for a key term i.e. 'core animation' is to 'animate objects at runtime' as '(x)' is to 'connected iPhones to internet programmatically'

I was hoping there is an objective c version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try dispatch_async if you are trying to do rest calls. If you are trying cross platform dev on mobile phones, try apache cordova

Comment: this seems to be what i am looking for. I just hope it isn't too good to be true. I like how there is an api to control device hardware/and software built in but would you still recommend them for functionality such as connecting to wifi/server data?

Comment: I'm taking that as a yes